# I get the following error when trying to send a message to my phone number from my Twilio number

Tags: python, twilio

I get the following error when trying to send a message to my phone number from my Twilio number

```
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient as TRC
    client = TRC('AC**********************edc','a7b***************************3d2') # connect to an account
    client.messages.create(from_='+17********25', to='+23***********27', body='Twilio\'s the best!!') #create the message

    Traceback
    TwilioRestException: The From phone number +17*******25 is not a valid,
    SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.
```

Can someone pls help me out?

Comment: Did you verify that phone number with Twilio? https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/whats-the-difference-between-a-verified-phone-number-and-a-twilio-phone-number?utm_source=stack_overflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon Also you may want to use their phone validator to verify the whole number you are using: https://www.twilio.com/lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure to add the `from_` number to your Twilio account on your [Account's phone numbers page](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers). [Error 21606](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21606) may have more information regarding this issue. If this is using your "test credentials" you will want to have a look at [test credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21606#test-credentials).

Answer (score 0):

The twilio number (Your from number: should be sms-enabled) that you have bought doesn't seem to have Capabilities of sending smses.